# Is there a relation between polarity of molecules and their electric susceptibility?

Tags: water, molecules, polarity, conductivity

So it is written in our text that electric susceptibility ($χe$) (the response of say water molecules in the presence of an external electric field) is related to the molecular behaviour of various substances, but it doesnt explore it, and says its out of scope for me. When I tried to find the related equations, I could not find a clear answer.

To be more clear,

We know that the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor increases when  water(k, dielectric constant = 80) is inserted as a dielectric as opposed to oil (k = 2.2), or any other non-polar substances (with small values of k). Now my question is, whether the dielectric constant (related to electric susceptibility as $k=χe + 1$) depends on the polarisation of the molecule.
Also, given $$P = χe. E$$ where P is the dipole moment per unit volume, called polarisation of the linear isotropic dielectric.

Can I tell someone that the reason Dielectric constant of water (80) is so much higher than oil (2.2) is because water is polar and oil is non polar. If so, what equation should I quote as proof to this statement?

To me it seems empirically true, but I would like to see if the theory supports the fact that polar molecules have a higher electric susceptibility as compared to non polar ones.

Comment: I might be totally out of track, but susceptibility is more on the "flexibility" of electrons arrangement,  independently of permanent electric dipoles. Actually, at least at qualitative level, I would perhaps look at polar molecules as not inherently polarisable (though very polar molecules can even undergo internal charge transfer under various stimuli).

Comment: Electric susceptibility is equal to relative permittivity (or the dielectric constant) minus 1: $\chi_e=\epsilon_r-1$

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti I disagree. That's the material polarisability. OP intend molecular susceptibility. If not, or s/he had not a distinction in mind, the question must be improved in order to known what we shall speak about.

Comment: @Alchimista What is molecular susceptibility? I have only come across the term susceptibility in the context of magnetism. I got that definition from the wikipedia page for electric susceptibility (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility). But yes, I agree the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti yes correct. But scroll down. The fact that the molecule is immerse in its own field is what makes the treatment different. Uno thing is the arrangement of water molecules in response to an external field. Another thing is the arrangement of the electrons within one water molecule in response to an external field. Another difference is that in the first case one can use the vacuum permittivity, while the same isn't true at molecular level.

Comment: Am sorry for any confusion caused, but I meant electric susceptibility as pointed out by @ShoubhikRMaiti. I was not aware that any other type of susceptiblitiy existed. I definitely mean the arrangement of polar water molecules in response to an external field.

Comment: @KrishnarajPT they are the same quantity. Just if you want to link it to molecular electrical dipole moment than the susceptibility is that of the molecule, not that of the block of matter that those molecules made up. Is is like volume of a sphere and volume of the things that make up the sphere. As usual the microscopic case is more complicated. Here is because you can't make use of the fact that a piece of matter can be treated to be immersed in vacuum, so the use of vacuum permittivity. The same notions is difficult to be applied inside the molecule.